# How to customize the Linux Mint's session buttons?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I have Linux Mint 18 with Cinnamon, and set up a dual-boot with (1) Linux Mint, and (2) Windows 7.

I would like to have a custom button that allows me to reboot directly into Windows from Linux Mint.

I already configured the GRUB and everything works with the `# grub-reboot 1` and `# reboot` commands, but now I would like to do it from the session panel.

This is what it looks like by default:

[image: Default session panel]

And this is what I want to get:

[image]

Is it possible to do? If yes (surely is), how?

Thanks in advance.